# Why does $C_G(g)$ have index $q$ if $|G| = pq$ and $|g| = p$ for all nonidentity $g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying [Abstract Algebra, 3rd Edition by Dummit and Foote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471433349). In Section 4.4 (Automorphism), one of the examples proves that $G$ is abelian if both of the following hold.

1. $|G| = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes (not necessarily distinct) with $p \le q$
2. $p \nmid q-1$

The second part of the proof further assumes $Z(G) = 1$ and states

3. every nonidentity element of $G$ has order $p$ $\implies$ $C_G(g)$ has index $q$ for all nonidentity $g \in G$

The proof next states that, if the right-hand side of #3 is true, then the class equation for $G$ reads $pq = 1 + kq$, which is impossible. Therefore, the proof states, there must exist $x \in G$ with order $q$.

Question: Why is #3 true?

### Attempt 1

Let $x$ be a nonidentity element of $G$. $C_G(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$. Because cosets of a subgroup partition $G$, and each coset is of the same size, if we can say $|C_G(x)| = p$, then it must be the case that $C_G(x)$ has index $q$.

$x$ commutes with any $x^i$ where $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $x^i \in C_G(x)$. Additionally, $x, x^2, ..., x^{p}$ are all distinct because $|x| = p$. Therefore $C_G(x)$ is of size at least $p$, containing $x, x^2, ..., x^p$.

Now assume $y \in C_G(x)$ where $y \ne x^i$ for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. This *should* lead to a contradiction... (but how?)

### Attempt 2

For any $g \in G$, there is a bijection between the elements of $G/C_G(g)$ and the elements of the conjugacy class of $g$. Therefore, for any nonidentity $x \in G$, if we can show that the size of the conjugacy class of $x$ is $q$, it follows that $C_G(x)$ has index $q$... (but how do we show that?)

Comment: If $G$ has order $pq$ it must have an element of order $q$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Can you give an example of the sort of group you are interested in?  As it stands, your assumptions are not consistent.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I actually can't see why $|G| = pq$ implies that $G$ must have an element of order $q$ in general, but I'm guessing Cauchy's theorem should tell exactly that, which apparently I'll be seeing in the next section of the text :)

This proof in question later states that it leads to a contradiction and thus there has to be an element of order $q$. I edited the question. I hope it's more coherent now.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.  Yes...in general, if a prime divides the order of a group then that group has an element of that prime order.  Very important fact about finite groups.  But if those assumptions are intended to lead to a contradiction, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your attempt $1$: suppose $|C_G(x)|>p$. Since $\langle x\rangle$ is a subgroup of $C_G(x)$ of order $p$ it is obvious from Lagrange's theorem that $|C_G(x)|=|G|$ and hence $C_G(x)=G$. So $x$ commutes with all elements in $G$ and hence $x\in Z(G)$ which is a contradiction to the center being trivial.